# Data for each is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I am creating a sample program using Ionic 3 in which I have used the SQLite to store the data. I have used a common insert query which will split the columns and values and store those details in the database but when I tried to run the program it shows me the error data for each is not a function.
I have used for each loop to split the columns and values but I have used the same in Ionic 1 - AngularJS JavaScript where it works fine.can anyone tell me what is wrong in the following code?

```
insert(tblName, data) {
console.log('insert function in db got called: ', data);
this.columns = [];
this.values = [];
data.forEach(function (value, column) {
  this.columns.push(column);
  this.values.push(value);
  console.log('columns', this.columns);
  console.log('values', this.values);
});
console.log('columns: ', this.columns);
console.log('values: ', this.values);
var question = (Array(this.columns.length + 1).join('?,')).slice(0, -1);
return new Promise(resolve => {
  var insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO ' + tblName + ' (' + this.columns.join(', ') + ') VALUES ('  + question + ');';
  console.log('insertQuery: ', insertQuery);
  this.db.executeSql(insertQuery, this.values, (r) => {
    console.log('Inserted... Sucess..', this.values);
    this
      .getRows()
      .then(s => {
        resolve(true)
      });
  }, e => {
    console.log('Inserted Error', e);
    resolve(false);
  })
})  
}
```

Error Part:

```
data.forEach(function (value, column) {
  this.columns.push(column);
  this.values.push(value);
  console.log('columns', this.columns);
  console.log('values', this.values);
});
```

Comment: is data an array?

Comment: simple, data is not array.. dont u get that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it could be a type error, are you sure that `data` is an `Array`? If **true**, move on to the next point, otherwise, you're just writing wrong javascript not wrong ts.

The thing is, Typescript has to know what kind of parameters are you working on.

```js
insert(tblName, data) {
  console.log('insert function in db got called: ', data);

  this.columns = [];
  this.values = [];

  data.forEach(function (value, column) {
    this.columns.push(column);
    this.values.push(value);

    console.log('columns', this.columns);
    console.log('values', this.values);
  });
}
```

The insert method is documented anywhere?
could you edit it:

```js
insert(tbName: string, data: any[]) {}
```